# validation the max length of ant design InputNumber in react

Tags: reactjs, validation, input, antd

I have an antd `InputNumber` in `Form.Item` in a react project.
My validation for this input is checking the length of input value.

This is my code:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Form.Item
        label="Value"
        name="numberValue"
        rules={[
          {
            pattern: /^(?:\d*)$/,
            message: "Value should contain just number",
          },
          {
            maxLength: 50,
            message: "Value should be less than 50 character",
          },
        ]}
        validateTrigger="onBlur"
      >
        <InputNumber
          onChange={(value) => {
            this.props.setValue(value);
          }}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    );
  }
```

I have two problems:

1. I want to show the `Value should contain just number` messages when user enter non numeric character. But this message doesn't show at all.
2. I want to show the `Value should be less than 50 character` message, when user enter the number/value with more than 10 character. But now, with entering the first character, this message will be shown!

Answer (score 6):

Depends on which validation library are you using.

`InputNumber` max is `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, so maybe use a simple `<Input>` with a pattern matcher:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Form.Item
        label="Value"
        name="numberValue"
        rules={[
          {
            pattern: /^(?:\d*)$/,
            message: "Value should contain just number",
          },
          {
            pattern: /^[\d]{0,50}$/,
            message: "Value should be less than 50 character",
          },
        ]}
        validateTrigger="onBlur"
      >
        <Input
          onChange={(value) => {
            this.props.setValue(value);
          }}
        />
      </Form.Item>
    );
  }
```

Comment: I want to check the length of input value.
 `max` check the value. I tested `max` before, it will check the value. for example when I enter 51 as a value, the related message will be shown

Comment: I've edited the solution, just add `type: "number"` to the rule. It should work.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it's not working yet.  it is the same

Comment: Oh, I get it. InputNumber has a limit, it cannot reach 50 chars anyways. I've added a solution that works with simple <Input>

Comment: https://ant.design/components/input-number/#API states that max is Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, maybe you can change that.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to define the length of the input:

```
<Form.Item
    label="Value"
    name="numberValue"
    rules={[
      {
        pattern: /^(?:\d*)$/,
        message: "Value should contain just number",
      },
      {
        max: 50,
        message: "Value should be less than 50 character",
      },
    ]}
    validateTrigger="onBlur"
  >
    <InputNumber
      onChange={(value) => {
        this.props.setValue(value);
      }}
    />
  </Form.Item>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<InputNumber 
    type="number" 
    placeholder="00" 
    parser={(value) => { 
        return value.substring(0, 2)
    }} 
/>
```

---

It will allow to wright only 2 digit.
If you want to allow more than just change substring value 2

Answer (score 1):

You use maxlength in `<Input />` and `type='number'` must in rules

```
<Input maxLength={50}
    onChange={e => getValue(e.target.value)}
    rules={[{ type: 'number' }]} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The native input tag it self won't support input tag which has type='number' to use maxLength. MaxLength works with text.

[Link to the Github Ant Design issue.](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/26274)

Ant Design has nothing to do with this.

Instead you can use as bellow code to limit the number.

```
<Input 
  onChange={(e) =>
    e.target.value.length <= 10 &&
    handleChange(e.target.value)
  }
  type='number'
/>
```